# Bluetooth disappears after lastest update

Tags: 18.04, bluetooth

After applying the latest 18.04 update to my Dell Precision 5520, bluetooth has completely disappeared.

[Bluetooth settings screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2Zdr.png)

This happened once before and rectified itself after the next update. I've tried rebooting hoping it was transient but no luck.

This is the full dmesg log from the last boot. There are errors related to USB but I don't know how that relates.

dmesg log: https://pastebin.com/HC6sBa72

These are the updates that were applied this morning. There is nothing that appears directly related to bluetooth or wireless in there.

```
Start-Date: 2018-10-28  09:36:52
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.365'
Install: linux-headers-4.15.0-38-generic:amd64 (4.15.0-38.41, automatic), linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-38-generic:amd64 (4.15.0-38.41, automatic), linux-modules-4.15.0-38-generic:amd64 (4.15.0-38.41, automatic), linux-headers-4.15.0-38:amd64 (4.15.0-38.41, automatic), linux-image-4.15.0-38-generic:amd64 (4.15.0-38.41, automatic)
Upgrade: libpackagekit-glib2-18:amd64 (1.1.9-1ubuntu2.18.04.1, 1.1.9-1ubuntu2.18.04.3), update-manager-core:amd64 (1:18.04.11.5, 1:18.04.11.6), linux-headers-generic:amd64 (4.15.0.36.38, 4.15.0.38.40), friendly-recovery:amd64 (0.2.38, 0.2.38ubuntu1), linux-libc-dev:amd64 (4.15.0-36.39, 4.15.0-38.41), libapt-inst2.0:amd64 (1.6.3ubuntu0.1, 1.6.6), grub-common:amd64 (2.02-2ubuntu8.6, 2.02-2ubuntu8.7), linux-image-generic:amd64 (4.15.0.36.38, 4.15.0.38.40), apt:amd64 (1.6.3ubuntu0.1, 1.6.6), update-manager:amd64 (1:18.04.11.5, 1:18.04.11.6), google-chrome-stable:amd64 (70.0.3538.67-1, 70.0.3538.77-1), grub2-common:amd64 (2.02-2ubuntu8.6, 2.02-2ubuntu8.7), gdm3:amd64 (3.28.3-0ubuntu18.04.1, 3.28.3-0ubuntu18.04.3), libapt-pkg5.0:amd64 (1.6.3ubuntu0.1, 1.6.6), packagekit-tools:amd64 (1.1.9-1ubuntu2.18.04.1, 1.1.9-1ubuntu2.18.04.3), grub-pc:amd64 (2.02-2ubuntu8.6, 2.02-2ubuntu8.7), linux-signed-generic:amd64 (4.15.0.36.38, 4.15.0.38.40), gir1.2-gdm-1.0:amd64 (3.28.3-0ubuntu18.04.1, 3.28.3-0ubuntu18.04.3), grub-pc-bin:amd64 (2.02-2ubuntu8.6, 2.02-2ubuntu8.7), libxnvctrl0:amd64 (410.66-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1, 410.73-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1), libgdm1:amd64 (3.28.3-0ubuntu18.04.1, 3.28.3-0ubuntu18.04.3), grub-efi-amd64-bin:amd64 (2.02-2ubuntu8.6, 2.02-2ubuntu8.7), man-db:amd64 (2.8.3-2, 2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1), python3-update-manager:amd64 (1:18.04.11.5, 1:18.04.11.6), packagekit:amd64 (1.1.9-1ubuntu2.18.04.1, 1.1.9-1ubuntu2.18.04.3), apt-utils:amd64 (1.6.3ubuntu0.1, 1.6.6), light-themes:amd64 (16.10+18.04.20180421.1-0ubuntu1, 16.10+18.04.20181005-0ubuntu1), ubuntu-artwork:amd64 (1:16.10+18.04.20180421.1-0ubuntu1, 1:16.10+18.04.20181005-0ubuntu1), grub-efi-amd64-signed:amd64 (1.93.7+2.02-2ubuntu8.6, 1.93.8+2.02-2ubuntu8.7), gir1.2-packagekitglib-1.0:amd64 (1.1.9-1ubuntu2.18.04.1, 1.1.9-1ubuntu2.18.04.3), apt-transport-https:amd64 (1.6.3ubuntu0.1, 1.6.6), gstreamer1.0-packagekit:amd64 (1.1.9-1ubuntu2.18.04.1, 1.1.9-1ubuntu2.18.04.3), linux-generic:amd64 (4.15.0.36.38, 4.15.0.38.40), ubuntu-mono:amd64 (16.10+18.04.20180421.1-0ubuntu1, 16.10+18.04.20181005-0ubuntu1), nvidia-settings:amd64 (410.66-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1, 410.73-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1)
End-Date: 2018-10-28  09:38:34
```

I'd love to be able to diagnose this myself but don't have the depth of skills yet to know what to do or where to look. Any idea's or direction would be much appreciated

Comment: I was also having trouble with Vmware workstation after the update. It seems tied to secure boot. After disabling that in the firmware everything started working again.

Not a great fix but it's working now